# Filtering when two tables must both be constrained

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

My report is largely working as I want it to, but some records are being omitted incorrectly.

I want to show every record for a person with a certain value ("2016 Campaign") in the Name field of their "Proposal" table. Also using a subreport, I want to show all "Action" records for that person with "2016 Campaign" contained in an Action table field called "Proposal".

This all works fine, except people without qualifying Action records are being omitted from the report entirely. I want to include "2016 Proposal" Actions in that subreport block, but I still want people to show up even if they *don't* have Action records with this value. How can I solve this?

[image: Proposal Report]

Comment: can you include some details of your table and the result you wanted? Even image its fine.

Comment: just show more details and result you wanted.. even just image its fine..

Comment: I added an image to the original post. At the top is a results line of the report. Two subreports showing, for Events and Actions linked with the Constituent. This works correctly - my problem is just that I am *only* getting results for people who have Actions to show! (I still want to see people we have proposed, if they have no actions).

Further down in the image I've included the table structure, which is a bit of a monster. Three exports from Raiser's Edge are coming together here (the constituent's data (circled red), and Event and Actions data (circled blue).

Comment: Thanks so much for any advice you can give.

This report shows data for people who have a Proposal record with name = "2016 Campaign". In the Actions subreport I include any Actions with Action Name field = "2016  Campaign". However, I'd still like to see the person's info if there are no qualifying Actions, and that's the problem (which is tricky to explain).

Comment: what joins have you used? and how is the data in database?

Comment: Where is your query came from? are putting your query in the report itself? (odbc connection with command?).

Comment: Thanks for the replies, and sorry I was not able to respond sooner.

The data comes from three separate exports from Raiser's Edge which I have imported to the report. From the past, I am familiar with filtering problems like this one (when I have connected the tables from two exports) and have solved it using left inner joins rather than the default outer joins, In this case, I've tried both to no avail.